# question about copy constructor

Tags: c++

I have this class:

```
class A {
private:
 int player;
public:
 A(int initPlayer = 0);
 A(const A&);
 A& operator=(const A&);
 ~A();
 void foo() const;
};
```

and I have function which contains this row:

```
 A *pa1 = new A(a2);
```

can somebody please explain what exactly is going on, when I call `A(a2)` compiler calls copy constructor or constructor, thanks in advance

Comment: A copy constructor _is_ a constructor.

Comment: What does your C++ textbook say? which textbook are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `a2` is an instance of `A`, this calls the copy constructor.

It will call `operator new` to get dynamic memory for the object, then it will copy-construct a new object into the memory, then return a pointer to that memory.

Answer (score 4):

When you call new A(a2);

It will call one of the constructors.
Which one it calls will depend on the type of a2.

If a2 is an int then the default constructor is called.

```
A::A(int initPlayer = 0);
```

If a2 is an object of type A then the copy constructor will be called.

```
A::A(const A&);
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the data type of `a2`. If it is `int` or a type that can implicitly be converted to `int`, the default c'tor (`A(int player=0)`) will be called, if `a2` is an instance of `A` or an type that can implicitly be converted to `A` (i.e. instance of a sub-class) the copy c'tor will be called.